# Is there a way to remove a button and then recreate it to generate different text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, button, methods

this is my first post and I am very new with JavaScript. For an assignment, I need to create a multiple-choice quiz that has several questions. My code pulls from an array of objects and creates buttons that have the four answer options. My issue(one of them anyway), is that after answering correctly, the buttons do not disappear but rather the function adds more buttons underneath them. I'm looking to remove the created buttons in order to replace them with the next series of buttons after the question has been answered correctly. I tried the .remove method but the only way I could was by the div ID which deleted all of it and when I tried getElementsByClassName, I encountered an error. It's definitely due to my inexperience but if anyone can help me solve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it. I need to use vanilla JS, please no jQuery. This is what my conflicting code looks like presently after trying to experiment. If I need to supply more information, I can. Thank you!

```
function renderQuestion() {
    var newQuestion = document.getElementById("question");
    var newAnswers = document.getElementById("answerBtns");
        newQuestion.textContent = questions[currentQuestion].question;
        for (i = 0; i < questions[currentQuestion].answers.length; i++){
        let btnEl = document.createElement('button');
        btnEl.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success bg-gradient btn-lg");
        btnEl.setAttribute("value", questions[currentQuestion].answers[i]);
        btnEl.textContent = questions[currentQuestion].answers[i];
        newAnswers.append(btnEl);
        btnEl.addEventListener("click", answerCheck);
        }
};


//Function to check chosen answer with answer in data

function answerCheck(btnEl) {
    // var btnEl = document.getElementsByClassName(".btn")
    if (questions[currentQuestion].correct == btnEl.target.textContent) {
        score += 1;
        console.log("Correct! You got this! Your score is " + score);
        let element = document.querySelectorAll("button");
        element.remove()
        currentQuestion++
        renderQuestion();
    } else {
        secondsLeft -= 5;
        console.log("Wrong :( Try again!");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community.
A couple of comments:

You've used i in your for loop without declaring it with let, var, or const. This could potentially cause issues because i will be in the global scope. Always declare loop variables to avoid unexpected behavior.

You also want to loop through and remove buttons. When you try to use element.remove(), it won't work because remove is a method on individual elements, not on a NodeList. You need to loop through the NodeList and call remove on each button.

Comment: Don't add new buttons every time. Create the buttons in the original HTML. Then you can change their text by assigning to `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`.

Comment: Unless the assignment has specific requirements, @Barmar suggestion will be your simplest solution. The only caveat that you would need to take into consideration is if all of your questions have the same number of potential answer options or not.

Comment: Anyway, the simple solution is to do `newAnswers.innerHTML = ''` before you add the buttons for the next question. That will remove all the old buttons.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I knew there had to be a more efficient/effective way to go about it but by that point I had little time left and little knowledge/experience in JS that I had to go with it before the due date. It wasn't my original idea but it was the one that worked at the time within my scope. I learned a lot though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `checkAnswer()` function is returning a list of all `<button>` elements, and then trying to remove the *list*. But `.remove()` is meant to be called on [individual *elements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove). You could loop through the list and call `.remove()` on each item, or use [@barbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)’s second suggestion to empty out the div wrapping the answer.

Also, friendly note: the parameter for `.querySelectorAll()` behaves [exactly like CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#parameters), so by passing it `"button"`, you’re getting the list of all `<button>` elements on the entire page. If you have other buttons besides the answers, it could be problematic.